# How to convert byte[] to Binary to set jcr:data with file contents?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, jcr

I am trying to save binary data (image) into a JCR node. I'm fetching an image from an evernote Note using this method: [public byte[] getBody()](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/javadoc/com/evernote/edam/type/Data.html#getBody()) and then trying to set property jcr:data with the contents of the file using [setProperty(string, Binary)](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream))

This is how I'm doing this:

```
Node n; 
byte [] fileContent = resrouce.getData().getBody();
....
n.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "image/png");
n.setProperty("jcr:data", fileContent);
```

However, I get an error that

> no suitable method found for setProperty(java.lang.String,byte[])

What is a way to set `jcr:data` property with file contents that are in binary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [ValueFactory](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/ValueFactory.html) to convert the InputStream to a [Binary](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Binary.html) value.
The ValueFactory can be got from the [Session](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html) object.

```
ValueFactory factory = session.getValueFactory();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);

Binary binary = factory.createBinary(is);
Value value = factory.createValue(binary);
n.setProperty("jcr:data", value);
```

To learn more about writing to the repository, refer to this [specification](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/10_Writing.html).

Comment: That's a dead link (specification = http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/10_Writing.html)